# roslaunch: [ ] is neither a launch file in package [ ] nor is [ ] a launch file name

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I know a lot of answers to this kind of problem are lurking around, but I swear everything I tried isn't working. I've sourced the environment multiple times manually, or adding `source/home/alexis/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` inside the `~./bashrc` file. I am positive the folder and files do exist. I've also built it multiple times via `catkin build` or `catkin_make`.

But still, whenever I run the command:

```
roslaunch catkin_ws map_navigation_stage_psu.launch
```

the error that is in the title shows up. I honestly don't know what to do anymore.

The content of "map_navigation_stage_psu.launch" is as follow:

```
<launch>
      <include file="$(find catkin_ws)/src/turtlebot/navigation/map_navigation/launch/turtlebot_stage_psu.launch"/>
     <node name="map_navigation" pkg="catkin_ws" type="map_navigation_node" output="screen">
     </node>
</launch>
```

Thank you for bearing with me

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285302/roslaunch:-%5B-%5D-is-neither-a-launch-file-in-package-%5B-%5D-nor-is-%5B-%5D-a-launch-file-name/) by [Alexis](https://answers.ros.org/users/34114/alexis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-03-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> But still, whenever I run the command:

> ```
> roslaunch catkin_ws map_navigation_stage_psu.launch
> ```

`catkin_ws` is the name of the directory that contains your Catkin workspace. It is not a package.

`roslaunch` can only find (and `$(find ..)`) packages, not workspaces.

Try replacing `catkin_ws` with the actual package name and see if that works any better.

Also:

> `source/home/alexis/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` inside the `~./bashrc` file.

If this is not a typo, this line is missing a space between `source` and `/home/alexis/..`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5